# JavaScript async/await variable null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, async-await, es6-promise

I am using promises and async to wait for a web request to finish. The variable info is empty when displaying its value using console.log(infos);

I am unsure as to why and what I am doing wrong?

```
var processFruits = async () => {
    let infos = [];
    let fruits = ["apples", "pears", "bananas"]

    await fruits.forEach(async fruit => {
        let response = await getFruitInfo(fruit);
        infos.concat(response);
        console.log(response);
    });

    console.log(infos);
};

let getFruitInfo = (fruit) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("https://www.fruitmap.org/api/trees", {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `infos = infos.concat(response);`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: `forEach` doesn't work with async functions. Use a normal `for of` loop to run your promises sequentially or `Promise.all(...map...)` to run in parallel.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `getFruitinfo`!

Answer (score 1):

`.forEach()` doesn't return anything, so your outer `await` doesn't wait for anything.

You need to call `.map()`, which will return an array of the promises returned by the inner async callbacks.  You then need to call `Promise.all()` to turn that array of promises into a single promise to `await`:

```js
await Promise.all(array.map(async ...));
```

Comment: Sorry I am confused but what you mean by calling .map() to the inner async arrays

Answer (score 0):

`.concat` doesn't modify your original reference but it creates a new one, that's why your `infos` array is still empty.

```js
var processFruits = async () => {
    let infos = [];
    let fruits = ["apples", "pears", "bananas"]

    fruits.forEach(async fruit => {
        let response = await getFruitInfo(fruit);
        infos = infos.concat(response); // here
        console.log(response);
    });

    console.log(infos);
};

let getFruitInfo = (fruit) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("https://www.fruitmap.org/api/trees", {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        reject(error);
    });
});

processFruits();
```